# How can I use DNAT on mangle table?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, ip

Can I use DNAT on mangle table?

If yes, then how?

If no, then are there any alternative to DNAT on mangle table or any outher table (but not NAT)?

Because I don't have a NAT table in my `iptables` (I have mangle raw ... etc but do not have NAT).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use DNAT in the `mangle` table (nor any other kind of NAT).

Both DNAT and SNAT (and special cases of this, like MASQUERADE and REDIRECT) only work in the `nat` table, or more specifically:

- DNAT only works in the `nat` table of the `PREROUTING` and `OUTPUT` chain.
- SNAT only works in the `nat` table of the `POSTROUTING` and `INPUT` chain.

If this is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please explain why you think you need to use DNAT in the `mangle` table.

Comment: Because I don't have a NAT table in my iptables , i want to forward traffic to a proxy(transparent proxy)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see nat table, that means you need to load iptable_nat module on your kernel.

> modprobe iptable_nat

If this command give you error, It means your kernel didn't compiled with that module.

Comment: my  kernel didn't compiled with that module so now what i need to do

Comment: @RajuHaldarRH3X4R You need to compile the kernel by enabling nat module on your kernel config. Which linux distro and kernel are you using? This module should be  already enabled by default on most current distros

Comment: genymotion android emulator